# My vba row finder not working

Tags: vba, long-integer, msgbox

whats wrong with this code

```
Sub wahwah()


Dim lastrow As Long


lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
MsgBox _
"The last row is: " & lastrow


End Sub
```

Comment: you didnt make any changes

Comment: `x1Up` isn't the same as `xlUp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be 
    xlUp
however you use 
    x1Up